# Database Normalization and Structure

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, theory, database-theory

I have a data stucture that has the following tables

```
Customers
Transactions (Type A)
Transactions (Type B)
```

We are adding a `Comments` Table

`Customers` have one more more of `Transactions A` and `Transactions B`
`Comments` can be related to either the `Transactions` or the `Customer`

We are having an internal discussion on the database format.

One side wants to create a Comments table and 3 cross tables.
One side wants to create a Comments Table with a foreign key to the customer and 2 nullable keys to the transactions.

Is there a Normal Form rule that says one is better than the other? Is there any consensus?

EDIT:

More answers and specifics

- Comments will never be associated with more than one customer
- Comments will never be associated with more than one transaction
- Comments will only ever be associated with Transaction A, Transaction B, or neither; but never both
- Customers and Transactions may have 0 or more comments

Comment: I vote for "...create a Comments Table with a foreign key to the customer and 2 nullable keys to the transactions".  IMHO...  PS: Is there any chance a combination of Transaction ID + Transaction Date (for example) would be unique system-wide?  Some "combined foreign key" that uniquely identified a transaction (regardless of type a or type b), that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: More information would be helpful. Is it legal for a comment to be associated with multiple customers, or multiple transactions of the same type (A or B)? Is it legal for a comment to be associated with a customer, a transaction A, and a transaction B? Is it required for a comment to have some or any of these relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important Normal Forms (1NF-6NF,BCNF and derivatives) don't allow nulls in tables because all of them are based only on relations with values, not nulls. More usefully there is a design principle called the Principle of Orthogonal Design which specifies that tuples with the same attributes  should not be permitted to appear in multiple places in your schema. It seems likely that your two transaction tables and having comments in multiple places would break that rule of Orthogonal Design.

You could create a parent transaction table that combines the common attributes of your two transaction tables, including the comment attribute (supertype/subtype pattern).

Comment: The two transactions are completly unique. So your vote is for a single comment table and cross tables to each of the transactions and the customer?

Comment: They aren't "unique" if they will share the same attributes - they overlap. Tables with overlapping sets of attributes are usually best avoided. *One* table associating a comment with the transaction identifier should do it and would avoid the need for multiple nullable columns.